# boost serialization and doubles

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, floating-point, boost-serialization

I am trying to serialize a class to a string using the boost serialization library and included in my class are several double member variables.

Below is the code I'm using to serialize:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

std::stringstream ss;
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
oa << mPoint;
```

Here is the serialiation method within my Point class:

```
friend class boost::serialization::access;

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    if (version > 0)
    {
        ar & mLatitude;
        ar & mLongitude;
    }
}
```

When I serialize to a string, boost doesn't appear to handle the double to string conversion as I would expect (there appear to be rounding issues).  Researching a bit it looks like others have reported the same behavior.  I also understand the precision related issues associated with converting a double to a string and vice versa and how this could cause the issue.

What is strange and I don't understand though is this doesn't appear to happen when I'm using a stringstream itself and redirecting the double to the stream nor when I use boost's lexical_cast function to convert from a stringstream.str() back to a double.  Before discovering boost had its own serialization/deserialization classes, I had actually written my own using stringstream and lexical_cast calls and it worked w/o issue.  I'm really hoping I don't have to abandon the serialization library and go back to what I had before.  Hopefully there is just some setting/trait/etc. I'm missing.

Comment: obvious and stupid suggestion would be to serialize it as a binary data, not as a string? Maybe that is the solution? Again if it was that easy you would probably do it already... :) I wouldnt be offering my advice if it wasnt a long time without answer and my curiosity to find out the solution.  :)

Comment: boost's lexical_cast has complex logic to set the precision of the stream appropriately - see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/detail/lcast_precision.hpp

Comment: Can you give an example of values that do and don't round-trip correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try forcing your stream to use scientific format for floating point before serialising to it:

```
ss << std::scientific;
```

It looks like the boost library sets the precision correctly, but doesn't appear to set the format. Alternatively, you can I think derive and override the logic for saving and/or loading floating point numbers without throwing away the rest of the library - start [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/archive/basic_text_oprimitive.hpp).

It also looks like there is [work in progress](http://lists.boost.org/boost-commit/2011/04/33978.php) on supporting infinities etc.

Comment: I had also modified the class to represent my data elements as float as opposed to double which looked to do the same and at least solved my issue with regards to serialization.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer the `Boost.Serialization` question, but is a possible workaround.

From the above question, it's not clear to me that you need a string representation or not. If you are looking for a cross-platform representation (binary or otherwise), consider using `protobuf`, which does have support for encoding `double`s.

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html#scalar